# Retrieve the application handle from SQL

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw

I would like to retrieve the [Application Handle](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.mon.doc/doc/r0001161.html) of the current connection via SQL, however I cannot find a way to do that.

There is a scalar function called [APPLICATION_ID](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0011856.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-4-15) that retrieves the ID of the current connection, but not the handle.

The [special registers](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008404.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-2-5) do not retrieve that neither.

I would like to retrieve that in SQL to use it in a stored procedure.

Comment: [MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE()](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0059835.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F3-6-1-3-10-14)

Comment: Great! can you put it like an answer. I did not specify the DB2 version and it works for me, however is there something equivalent in v9.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can query one of the monitor views, e.g.

```
select application_handle 
from sysibmadm.mon_connection_summary
where application_id = application_id()
```

In DB2 10.5 there is a function just for that:  `MON_GET_APPLICATION_HANDLE()`